# Databricks - Can we set environment variables for all clusters/using secret scopes in init scripts

Tags: variables, databricks, environment

I would like to use a databricks secret in an init script.
I can manually set an environment variable with `ENVVAR={{/secrets/myscope/mysecret}}` and then use ENVVAR in the init script.  However doing it this way I would have to manually set that environment variable on each cluster, and any new ones, which won't work in my scenario.

Ideally I would like to manage it with cluster policies, but I don't see that being available there.
I've also tried to have a separate init script with
`export ENVVAR="{{secrets/myscope/mysecret}}"`
But doing this when I try to echo that ENVVAR it returns nothing so I assume it is failing.

Does anyone have an idea on how I can achieve this?

Thanks
Mat

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track by using an init script, but you cannot use normal `export` since then the variable will only be available to the init script subprocess.

Instead, use the following line in an init script to set an environment variable globally:

```
sudo echo AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_HERE >> /etc/environment
```

This will write to the `environment` file of the cluster, which is read from any subprocess on the cluster.

**Better way:**
Even better than setting the secret inside an init script is to use Databricks secrets API directly in code, e.g. like this:

```
dbutils.secrets.get(scope="myscope", key="mysecret")
```

Read more here: https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html#dbutils-secrets

Comment: This does not work for shared clusters, as they re-set /etc/environment (for some reason) after running the global init scripts